# Docker container upload permission

Tags: linux, docker, ftp, upload

I started to play with docker. I'm using: https://laradock.io/ for my laravel project.

So I have docker on my laptop (making server out of it) which is connected to the same network that my desktop pc. At this point I can access the website on my pc and connect to ftp via fillezilla - everything works fine by this point.

But... i can't upload any files via filezilla. I can see all project data, but can't change it.

```
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,103,87,85).
Command:    STOR gw001.jpg
Response:   550 Permission denied.
Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

I've already changed chmod to 777 (yes I know - that's not secure, but I'm just trying everything at this point), also tried chown www-data 777. But nothing seems to work.

Previously on other container I had to install vsftp first and there I know I could change settings like write_permission. But the problem is that when I list all services running on Laradock containers, there is no vsftp/or anything that seems like ftp host so I don't even know how to change permissions.

Or maybe that's matter of some linux build in firewall

Comment: Is the ftp server running in the container or on the host? What distribution do you use (on host)?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you make your question more clear. It starts of appearing to be a question about docker, but then changes to be about ftp. Are you ftping to a server that is within docker. If so is your goal to set up an ftp server, or to get files in to your docker container?

Comment: FTP Server is running in container. Docker is on laptop and i try to connect to container via FTP from my desktop PC connected to the same local (not container-normal one) network as laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the solution and figured out what's going on.
Docker is mapping my laravel files into container, but I was actually connecting to Ubuntu on latptop via **Vsftpd** not to container.

That's ok because files are mapped in container anyway so all changes are live.

What was the solution.

Edited:

```
/etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Uncommented

```
write enable= YES
```

I can now upload files via Filezilla from Desktop to Laptop with container.